# How to place user control links in the top region of my website (as in stackexchange)?

Tags: users, theming

I would like to have a block, in the top right region of my website, that works pretty much like Drupal Answers. A login/register button for anonymous users and when the users are logged in, their username (and their profile picture) would appear with a dropdown menu giving them access to control features like their profile page, a logout link etc..

I'm fiddling around with tpl files but nothing shows up.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I'm fiddling around with tpl files but nothing shows up.

Don't forget to clear your Drupal cache after modifying .tpl.php files.

This can be done at **admin/config/development/performance** or using the `drush cc all` command via the [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) module.